# getting value of textbox from combo box

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can I get the value from combo box to textbox?

```
<script>
function getVal(e){
    var t2 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("text2").value = t2;
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is the issue or error you are facing in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/wnmcL/2/)

```
onchange="getVal();"

function getVal() {
  document.getElementById("text2").value = document.getElementById("model").value;
}
```

For more:- [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You already get the value in your variable e.
Change your code like this.

```
<script>
  function getVal(e){
    document.getElementById("text2").value = e;
 }
</script>
```